# How to dispose/clean MessageListener bean programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, imdb

I am using Spring3.1(standalone env)

I have created MDB by implements MessageListener which connected to a topic via templates.

this bean scope is singleton.

Sometimes I want to dispose that Listener Bean. when I say dispose I mean I want ioc to free that resource and clean this bean from the container.(which eventually will make this bean stop listening to messages and free un-used memory.)

1. I need to retrieve this bean by it's id with getBean(..) method to execute it's disposal. I heard that using getBean(..) can cause memory leaks. how should I make it otherwise?
2. Should I use singleton Scope or prototype one for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by getBean() and memory leaks but...

If you want to remove it completely, rather than just stop it, you can declare it in its own "child" application context. Make the main context a parent so it can reference beans in the main context (if necessary).

```
/**
 * Create a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext with the given parent,
 * loading the definitions from the given XML files and automatically
 * refreshing the context.
 * @param configLocations array of resource locations
 * @param parent the parent context
 * @throws BeansException if context creation failed
 */
public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String[] configLocations, ApplicationContext parent) throws BeansException {
    this(configLocations, true, parent);
}
```

When you want to remove it; call context.destroy().

Comment: So if Ill need 50 mdb's ill need to create 50 context? doesnt make sense.

Comment: I just like doing it that way; keeps things clean; using child contexts allows you to configure the beans using property placeholders and setting up the context's environment (in 3.1). If you don't want to do it that way, you can use AbstractBeanFactory factory = (AbstractBeanFactory) ctx.getBeanFactory();
  factory.destroySingleton("dmlc");

Comment: What about performences/memory leak if I use this way(the AbstractBeanFactory way)

Comment: Could you give simple example of your first solution? thanks.

Comment: I am not aware of any performance/memory leak issues. I'll see if I can find some time to build an example.

Comment: What about having prototypes being generated by the ioc?

Comment: What about them? If you're using prototypes, use                 public void destroyBean(String beanName, Object beanInstance) instead